# Unable to resolve this error while deploying the docker image to leverage GPU computational power in deep learning

Tags: docker, deep-learning, gpu, virtual-machine, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Recently I have started a deep learning project and I want to deploy it on a Ubuntu VM and then later on Google Vertex AI so to remove the different GPU compatibility issue i came across Nvidia-container-toolkit which helps with that.
These are the steps I followed:

1. I had the drivers successfully installed on the VM and I was able to see the GPU configurations using `nvidia-smi` command
2. I created a docker file and my main code file (PY File) where I am accessing the GPU functionality.
3. In the docker file I used the correct toolkit tag which I took from here --> https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/tags?page=1
   and my docker file looks something like this:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.2.0-devel-ubuntu20.04
CMD nvidia-smi

#Rest of my code
```

Now when I create the image the image is created successfully but when I run the container it gives me the error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].
```

I am using this command to run the container

```
docker run -d --gpus all --name mycontainer -p 5000:5000 test1
```

Can anyone suggest me what am I missing here? It is the Nvidia-container-toolkit needs to be installed on the host machine as well?